# Client refuses to accept project

Tags: difficult-client

I took on a project for a client, not taking any advance payment. I completed the project, but when the time came to deliver the project to the client, they said that they don't have that requirement any more, and they do not want the project.

In this case, what can I do? My client didn't pay me a single penny, and the time spent working on this project is a waste.

Comment: Quick question: did you have a contract with this client?

Comment: no , i didn't make any contract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is *exactly* you should require a contract and upfront deposit of some percentage of the final bill (usually 40-50%). You probably don't have much recourse legally unless you can prove that an email chain at the beginning of the project is detailed enough to constitute a contract.

Another thing that you can do is to take the client's new requirement and redo that part of the project. If you and the client were in constant communication throughout and they sprung the no-longer-a-requirement card, that's one thing. However, from the post, it sounds like the communication had been limited. Requirements do change, and sometimes you have to keep in constant contact with your client to make sure the project is still going in the right direction.

Frankly, your best bet is to chalk it up to a life lesson, spend some time to create a contract boilerplate (Contract Killer 3 is a sample starting point), and use it with your next project and next client.

Comment: It happened to me years ago... then I wrote a contract for following clients. No money for that project. Now I force myself doing nothing without the client signature on my contract :P I ask an upfront deposit to cover first piece of work.